# Batch return statements in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I do

```
INSERT INTO table DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id
```

which returns the ID, which is later used in the calling code. But if I do

```
INSERT INTO table DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id;
INSERT INTO table DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id;
INSERT INTO table DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id;
```

I only get the latest returned value.

What's a proper way to do it, as an either "do this n times" construct or a union of the above (which should work for any return query)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit the (lesser known fact) that you can run a SELECT statement without putting any column into the select list.

```
insert into the_table --<< no columns here!
select --<< no columns here either!
from generate_series(1,3);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bdf7752c4cd8d1b170415d58975c7e33)